# Почему функция не работает с двумя условиями?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть код Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#change').click(function(){
    if ($('#upload').attr('type') == 'file') {
        $('#upload').attr('type','text');
        $('#change').text('File');
    };
    if ($('#upload').attr('type') == 'text') {
        $('#upload').attr('type','file');
        $('#change').text('URL');
    };
});
```

});

И код HTML:

```
<li>
    <input type="file" name="upload-image" id="upload">
    <a id="change" href="#">URL</a>
</li>
```

Почему когда существует только одно условие, то функция работает и переключает атрибут, а если нет, тогда ничего не переключается? Как сделать, чтобы при КАЖДОМ клике атрибут менялся?

P.S. Я новичок и поэтому еще не совсем понимаю все тонкости языка.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/change-type-of-input-field-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

У вас условие написано неправильно. Попробуйте прочитать его. Если тип равен файл, то установи тип текст. И сразу же другое условие: если тип равно текст, то установи файл. Т.е. мы меняем с файл на текст и сразу же меняем обратно. Оттого и "не работает". Все там работает правильно. Вам нужно второй if заменить на else или внутри каждого из if поставить return false; после последней функции.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#change').click(function(){
    if ($('#upload').attr('type') == 'file') {
        $('#upload').attr('type','text');
        $('#change').text('File');
    } else { 
        if ($('#upload').attr('type') == 'text') {
            $('#upload').attr('type','file');
            $('#change').text('URL');
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lkry1ahL/